# answer for "symfony2 chained selectors" not clear

Tags: symfony-2.1

I have the same task that described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186185/symfony2-chained-selectors) topic.

When I am looking in the answer I cant get one thing. What url should be set in the ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#city_country').change(function(){
    $('#city_state option:gt(0)').remove();
    if($(this).val()){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: "country_id=" + $(this).val(),
            url: Routing.generate('state_list'),
            success: function(data){
                $('#city_state').append(data);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a route that points to a controller which accepts a country id and returns a list of state id's within that country.