# Add event listener to form element added by event listener

Tags: php, events, symfony

I'm building a Symfony app and using form events with some jquery/ajax to do the whole "state/locality" thing. I have a slight issue though, I am using the format Province -> City -> Suburb. Now as far as I can tell my code is fine, but when the execution hits the section where I add a listener to the "City" select, it throws an error saying the following:

`The child with the name "physicalCity" does not exist.`

This obviously happens when I try and add an event listener to the newly created field, thus adding an event listener to an element created by an event listener?

A section of the code is below... What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->add('schoolName')
            ->add('physicalProvince', 'entity', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => 'MY\MainBundle\Entity\Province',
                'empty_value' => 'Select a province',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'province',
                    'data-show' => 'physical-city',
                )
            ));

        /*
         * For the physical cities
         */
        $physicalCityModifier = function(FormInterface $form, Province $province = null) {
            if (null !== $province)
                $cities = $province->getCities();
            else
                $cities = array();

            $form->add('physicalCity', 'entity', array(
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => 'MY\MainBundle\Entity\City',
                'empty_value' => 'Select a province first',
                'choices' => $cities,
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'city physical-city',
                    'data-show' => 'physical-suburb'
                )
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($physicalCityModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if (is_object($data->getPhysicalSuburb()))
                    $province = $data->getPhysicalSuburb()->getCity()->getProvince();
                else
                    $province = null;

                $physicalCityModifier($event->getForm(), $province);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('physicalProvince')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($physicalCityModifier) {
                $province = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $physicalCityModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $province);
            }
        );

        /*
         * For the physical suburbs
         */
        $physicalSuburbModifier = function(FormInterface $form, City $city = null) {
            if (null !== $city)
                $suburbs = $city->getSuburbs();
            else
                $suburbs = array();

            $form->add('physicalSuburb', null, array(
                'choices' => $suburbs,
                'empty_value' => 'Select a city first',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'physical-suburb'
                ),
            ));
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($physicalSuburbModifier) {
                $data = $event->getData();
                if (is_object($data->getCity()))
                    $city = $data->getCity();
                else
                    $city = null;

                $physicalSuburbModifier($event->getForm(), $city);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('physicalCity')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) use ($physicalSuburbModifier) {
                $city = $event->getForm()->getData();

                $physicalSuburbModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $city);
            }
        );
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If anybody else has a similar issue, I eventually got it right with event subscribers for each field, with help from [this site](http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-selects-dependientes-mediante-eventos/) (translate it for those non-spanish speaking folk among us).

Bascially, what I did was create a new Subscriber class for each field, including province, and then just created a query builder inside each of them to populate their values with those from the preceding fields. The code is shown below.

AddProvinceFieldSubscriber.php

```
class AddProvinceFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $factory;
    private $fieldName;
    private $type;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, $fieldName) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName . 'Province';
        $this->type = $fieldName;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit',
        );
    }

    private function addProvinceForm(FormInterface $form, $province) {
        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed($this->fieldName, 'entity', $province, array(
            'class' => 'MyThing\MainBundle\Entity\Province',
            'mapped' => false,
            'empty_value' => 'Select a province',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
                return $qb;
            },
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'province ' . $this->type .'-province',
                'data-show' => $this->type . '-city',
            )
        )));
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (null === $data)
            return;

        $fieldName = 'get' . ucwords($this->type) . 'Suburb';
        $province = ($data->$fieldName()) ? $data->$fieldName()->getCity()->getProvince() : null;
        $this->addProvinceForm($form, $province);
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();

        if (null === $data)
            return;

        $province = array_key_exists($this->fieldName, $data) ? $data[$this->fieldName] : null;
        $this->addProvinceForm($form, $province);
    }
}
```

AddCityFieldSubscriber.php

```
class AddCityFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $factory;
    private $fieldName;
    private $provinceName;
    private $suburbName;
    private $type;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, $fieldName) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName . 'City';
        $this->provinceName = $fieldName . 'Province';
        $this->suburbName = $fieldName . 'Suburb';
        $this->type = $fieldName;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit',
        );
    }

    private function addCityForm(FormInterface $form, $city, $province) {
        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed($this->fieldName, 'entity', $city, array(
            'class' => 'MyThing\MainBundle\Entity\City',
            'empty_value' => 'Select a city',
            'mapped' => false,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($province) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c')
                                ->innerJoin('c.province', 'province');
                if ($province instanceof Province) {
                    $qb->where('c.province = :province')
                       ->setParameter('province', $province);
                } elseif (is_numeric($province)) {
                    $qb->where('province.id = :province')
                       ->setParameter('province', $province);
                } else {
                    $qb->where('province.provinceName = :province')
                       ->setParameter('province', null);
                }

                return $qb;
            },
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'city ' . $this->type . '-city',
                'data-show' => $this->type . '-suburb',
            )
        )));
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data) {
            return;
        }

        $fieldName = 'get' . ucwords($this->suburbName);
        $city = ($data->$fieldName()) ? $data->$fieldName()->getCity() : null;
        $province = ($city) ? $city->getProvince() : null;
        $this->addCityForm($form, $city, $province);
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data)
            return;

        $city = array_key_exists($this->fieldName, $data) ? $data[$this->fieldName] : null;
        $province = array_key_exists($this->provinceName, $data) ? $data[$this->provinceName] : null;
        $this->addCityForm($form, $city, $province);
    }
}
```

And finally AddSuburbFieldSubscriber.php

```
class AddSuburbFieldSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    private $factory;
    private $fieldName;
    private $type;

    public function __construct(FormFactoryInterface $factory, $fieldName) {
        $this->factory = $factory;
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName . 'Suburb';
        $this->type = $fieldName;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        return array(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData',
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT => 'preSubmit',
        );
    }

    private function addSuburbForm(FormInterface $form, $city) {
        $form->add($this->factory->createNamed($this->fieldName, 'entity', null, array(
            'class' => 'MyThing\MainBundle\Entity\Suburb',
            'empty_value' => 'Select a suburb',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($city) {
                $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('s')
                                ->innerJoin('s.city', 'city');

                if ($city instanceof City) {
                    $qb->where('s.city = :city')
                       ->setParameter('city', $city);
                } elseif (is_numeric($city)) {
                    $qb->where('city.id = :city')
                       ->setParameter('city', $city);
                } else {
                    $qb->where('city.cityName = :city')
                       ->setParameter('city', null);
                }
                    $sql = $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();

                return $qb;
            },
            'auto_initialize' => false,
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'suburb ' . $this->type . '-suburb',
            ),
        )));
    }

    public function preSetData(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data)
            return;

        $fieldName = 'get' . ucwords($this->fieldName);
        $city = ($data->$fieldName()) ? $data->$fieldName()->getCity() : null;
        $this->addSuburbForm($form, $city);
    }

    public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if (null === $data)
            return;

        $city = array_key_exists($this->type . 'City', $data) ? $data[$this->type . 'City'] : null;
        $this->addSuburbForm($form, $city);
    }
}
```

I had to add some extra stuff in there, but you get the gist of it.

In my form type I simply added the following:

```
$builder
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddProvinceFieldSubscriber($factory, 'postal'))
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddCityFieldSubscriber($factory, 'postal'))
    ->addEventSubscriber(new AddSuburbFieldSubscriber($factory, 'postal'))
//...
```

And happy days! Hope this helps somebody.

Also, I added the `data-show` attributes to simplify my AJAX process, just in case somebody was wondering.

Comment: Does this work while you edit this content as well. For me it didn't. Also could you please reply which version of Symfony did you work this with ?

Comment: Yes it worked for me. This was Sf 2.4 I believe, can't remember exactly. Just try and play with the query builder decision cases. Perhaps something in there is strange with your case. And install XDebug! Helps a lot.

Comment: Thank you very much for this example. This perfectly solved an approach to my form whereby multiple fields dynamically determine the choices of the next in a chained/stepped fashion. (The official Symfony example only supports 1 field deep, no chaining/stepping.) -- I'll post the URL to show an example of it once done.

Answer (score 0):

For those who prefer simplicity, you can relate whatever field you want to another by putting the logic into the controller.

So you can use ajax to check any change for a specific select and send the result to a method in your controller which will return the result fetched from your database.

Your dependent select box will then contains the specific options related to parent select.

Comment: Code example will add more value to your answer.