# How to dynamically modify a form field based on 2 other fields in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

The Symfony documentation explains how to add a field based on the value of an other field for a submitted form: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data

However, how to add a field based on the value of 2 other fields?

Let's say I have these 3 fields in my form:

- Category
- Brand
- Model

Each of these fields are `entity` fields, but only brands of the selected category should be shown (easily done with the mentioned cookbook, using the `FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT` event), and only models of the selected category and brand (if they are both submitted) should be shown in the list.

This means that I need to get the submitted values of both the brand *and* the model to get the list of available models.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use form event subscribers. More on that:

[Add event listener to form element added by event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20544442/add-event-listener-to-form-element-added-by-event-listener)

http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/

Comment: Thank you for the links, I didn't find them despite of my search!
I adapted the code to my needs and to Symfony 2.4, and it works fine. It is just too bad that only raw data (instead of mapped objects) can be used in PRE_SUBMIT events.

Comment: There is an updated version of the article for Symfony 2.4: http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/