# symfony2 ajax simple request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twig, symfony-2.5

Im learning programming with Symfony2 and I have some problems with AJAX request, but I dont know which are the errors.

I try refresh 2 combobox
Combobox1 has one list of name of some courses
Combobox2 has to refresh according to ComboBox1 id selection

Javascript

```
function ListarProgramas(codfacu)
{
    $('#SelProgramas').html('cargando...');
    var datos = "IdFacultad="+codfacu;
    $.post(Routing.generate('bibliotecaportada_listar_programas'),
        {IdFacultad: codfacu},
        function(data)
        {
            if(data.responseCode == 200 )
            {
                $('#SelProgramas').html(data.ProgramasHtml);
            }
        }, "json");
}

 HTML 

<select name="SelEspecie" id="SelEspecie" onchange="ListarProgramas(this.value)" style="width: 350px;text-align: center">
  <option value="0">SELECCIONE FACULTAD</option>
  {% for facultad in facultades %}
       <option  value="{{ facultad.Id }}">{{ facultad.facultad }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
</select>

Controller

public function listar_programasAction()
{
  $request = $this->get('request');
  $IdFacultad = $request->request->get('IdFacultad');
  if($IdFacultad)
  {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("bibliotecaportadaBundle:Programas");
    $Programas = $repository->findBy(array('IdFacultad' => $IdFacultad));
    $ProgramasHtml = "";
    foreach ($Programas as $Programa)
    {
      $ProgramasHtml .= "<option>".$Programa->getProgProf()."</option>";
    }
    $return = array("responseCode"=>200, "ProgramasHtml" => $ProgramasHtml);
  }
  else
  {
    $return=array("responseCode"=>400, "info"=>"<option>SELECCIONE PROGRAMA</option>");
  }
  $return = json_encode($return);//jscon encode the array
  return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));//make sure it has the correct content type
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [symfony2 chained selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186185/symfony2-chained-selectors)

Comment: Thanks Im going to do some changes