# How to get choice options from another entity in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

I want to load two choice list, the second one load only some values based on the first choice. But my problem comes first... how to load the EntityType values in the first list from a class that is not directly related to the current class (the form type class).

```
->add(
    'cliente',
    EntityType::class,
    array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Cliente',
        'choice_label' => 'nombre',
    )
)
```

But there is no one 'cliente' field in this entity, so it throws the message you know...

> Neither the property "cliente" nor one of the methods "getCliente()",
>   "cliente()", "isCliente()", "hasCliente()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Envio".

Please, do you know how to solve this issue? Any help is welcome!

Comment: what about 'mapped' => 'false' ??

Comment: It works! do you know how to add an event listener? I am trying to access this mapped field but it doesn't appear in the data or in the form (event->getData or event->getForm). I am trying this:

         $builder->get('cliente')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) {
                $form = $event->getForm();
                
                $data = $event->getData();

                dump($form);
....

Comment: I post an answer for the error. Check the way of getting the non mapped field and try with that.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error your form is for the entity Envio. If you want to create an EntityType choicelist based on the Cliente entity, you'll need a doctrine relation in your Envio class:

```
class Envio
{
     /*
      * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Cliente")
      */
     protected $cliente;
```

The error has no relation to your question about having 2 choicelists and changing the choices of your second list based on the first choice. You're probably best off using javascript for that and you'll have many choices from AJAX to limiting the choices on the fly depending on the value or innerText of the .

Comment: Sorry I didn't give complete info. The relation is between Envio - Tarifa - Cliente, so Envio and Tarifa entities are related but not directly. What I want to do is to select Cliente and then only load their (of the Cliente selected) Tarifa options.

Comment: But still if I understand correctly you want an Envio entity to eventually have a selected client? That seems to be what you're doing in the form. To do this with Symfony/Doctrine you'll need at least the relation I described in my answer. Using this ManyToOne and the ->add('cliente') in your form, you will get at least a full list of clients. Then you can use javascript to change the full list based on a previous choice of 'tarifa'

Comment: No, the Envio entity does not have client, it has one tarifa (fare) and that tarifa belongs to a client. So the client is not directly related to Envio entity. I've found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186185/symfony2-chained-selectors and I am trying just by now... hope it works...

Comment: My problem now is how to get which data (which option) is selected in the first select because this is an unmapped field. When I put PRE_SET_DATA the $form variable doesn't have anything selected... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

For that error you need to make the field as 'mapped' => false, so:

```
->add(
    'cliente',
    EntityType::class,
    array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Cliente',
        'choice_label' => 'nombre',
        'mapped' => false
    )
)
```

Then for getting the property in the controller you must do:

```
$cliente = $form->get('cliente')->getData();
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: I need to get the client in the EnvioType class. When the 'cliente' field changes it has to fire an event to load the next input choice of the form... Do you know how to access the field from the EnvioType class inside the addEventListener function? Thanks!